# Uncheck selectBooleanCheckbox just after user checked it if condition true

Tags: checkbox, primefaces

excuse my poor English ;)

I have tabView with 2 tab that have alternative rendered by a selectBooleanCheckbox so I did:

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="check" 
value="#{prestationComponent.prestation.condUnique}">
<p:ajax event="change" update="tabV"/>          
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>

<p:tabView id="tabV" orientation="top">
<p:tab title="#{refMessage_fr.taxe_condunique_title}"
rendered="#{prestationComponent.prestation.condUnique}">
</p:tab>
<p:tab title="#{refMessage_fr.taxe_formullelist_title}"
rendered="#{!prestationComponent.prestation.condUnique}">
</p:tab>
```

this work perfectly

In one of the tow tab, i have a list, so i want to let this tab active if the list has more than 1 element so  i changed my selectBooleanCheckbox to this:

```
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="check" 
    value="#{prestationComponent.prestation.condUnique}"
    onchange="if(#{prestationComponent.addPrestationFormulesList.size()>1}) {PF('messageDialogue').show();#{prestationComponent.prestation.setCondUnique(false)};}">
    <p:ajax event="change" update="tabV,check"/>            
    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

and this work with the tab with the list, it's sty active but the selectBooleanCheckbox stay checked

so I want to selectBooleanCheckbox stay unchecked when i checked it if(#{prestationComponent.addPrestationFormulesList.size()>1})

thank you.

==========================================EDIT====================================

I found the solution, i create a function in the managed bean that test the condition and set the value of check box to false if condition is true and i call it in the listener of the ajax event of the check box

```
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="check" 
    value="#{prestationComponent.prestation.condUnique}"
    onchange="if(#{prestationComponent.addPrestationFormulesList.size()>1}) PF('messageDialogue').show();">
    <p:ajax listener="#{prestationComponent.checkBoxListner()}" event="change" update="tabV,check"/>            
    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just disable the checkbox when the list has more than one element?

Comment: yes, the user can chose only one option, either a the list or one specific formula(cant be in the list), if he chose a list and fill it, if he want to change to the one formula there is this condition (set up by our customer, i don't know why), that the user can't change to the one formula if the list has more than 1 element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, i create a function in the managed bean that test the condition and set the value of check box to false if condition is true and i call it in the listener of the ajax event of the check box

```
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="check" 
    value="#{prestationComponent.prestation.condUnique}"
    onchange="if(#{prestationComponent.addPrestationFormulesList.size()>1}) PF('messageDialogue').show();">
    <p:ajax listener="#{prestationComponent.checkBoxListner()}" event="change" update="tabV,check"/>            
    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```